# Testing, mocking and verifying with local Spring Testconfiguration

Tags: spring, unit-testing, mocking, spring-test

I am playing a little bit around with Spring Boot 2 and unit tests.

I have found a very handy solution for testclasses and test configurations (which doesn't put all beans into the context for simple unit tests).

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = SomeServiceClassTestConfiguration.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
public class SomeServiceClassTest {

@Configuration
static class SomeServiceClassTestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SomeServiceClass someServiceclass() {
       return new SomeServiceClass(someDependency());
    }

    @Bean
    public SomeDependency someDependency() {
      return mock(SomeDependency.class);
    }

}

    @Test
    public void someTests() {
    // given
    ...
    // when
    ...
    //then
    ...
    }

}
```

But now I have the question on how to verify the call on the mock in each test? Like `verify(mockedDepenendcy).someMethod();`

Or is the described solution only a good solution for really isolated tests of isolated classes which doesn't have any dependencies?

Comment: And why would you need Spring for this? Create the class and mock yourself and test away. The fact that your application uses Spring doesn't mean you have to use it everywhere...

Comment: If you need do some action after every test try to play with `@After` (or `@Before` if you need do action before method)